# Pass return value to two different methods

Tags: java, dictionary

I have a class with two methods: the `startAPI()` calls the API classes to extract entities and returns the entities and the occurrence of the entities. I need this return value in two different methods from another class, but as soon as I call the second method (`countApiOcc()`) the map I pass is empty. How can I use the returned map in two different methods?

```
public class Topic {

    public void calculateNoFeedback(String language, List<String> api, List<String> corr) {
        Map<String, Object> apis = startAPI(api, textList);
        CountTopics countT = new CountTopics();
        ArrayList<String> topics = countT.getTopics(apis);
        countT.countApiOcc(topics, apis);
    }

    public Map<String, Object> startAPI(List<String> selectedAPI, List<String> text) {
        Map<String, Object> apisValues = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        //do stuff to extract the entities and return entities
        return apisValues;
    }
}
```

The `CountTopic()` class looks as follows, and, explained in short, user can select which or how many APIs he wants to use to extract entities and in the class `CountTopic()` the method `getTopics()` should find the topics every selected API found and `countApiOcc()` I need the frequency of the selected entities (all of this works) it is just the map I need in the second method.

```
public  ArrayList<String> getTopics(Map<String, Object> apiV) {
System.out.println("apiV: "+apiV);
        Iterator iterator = apiV.entrySet().iterator();
        mapSize = apiV.size();
        System.out.println("Size of the map: "+ mapSize);

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry entries = (Map.Entry)iterator.next();

            String key = entries.getKey().toString();

            switch(key) {

            case "valuesMS":
                Map<String, Object> mapMicrosoft = (Map<String, Object>) apiV.get(key);
                ArrayList<String> microsoft = (ArrayList<String>) mapMicrosoft.get("topicArrayMS");

                microsoftTopicLowerCase.addAll(microsoft);
                topicsMultiset.addAll(microsoft);

                break;

            case "valuesGate":
                Map<String, Object> mapGate = (Map<String, Object>) apiV.get(key);
                ArrayList<String> gate = (ArrayList<String>) mapGate.get("topicArrayGA");

                //store the values for finding the topics which are found from every selected API
                //store the values from the api to lower case to find the index later (needed for how often this api found the topic
                gateTopicLowerCase.addAll(gate);
                topicsMultiset.addAll(gate);

                break;  
            }

            iterator.remove(); 
        }

//rest code: compare the Arrays to find the same topics
```

Comment: Please include the source for `CountTopics` too, but my guess is you're modifying the map inside getTopics

Comment: Why is the map empty? What do you do in getTopics? You can either make a copy of the map to pass to countApiOcc, or make sure that getTopics (or any other method) doesn't modify the map. I strongly suggest the second.

Comment: sloution: debug

Comment: Also, as @ShubhenduPramanik suggested, learn how to use a debugger. It will dramatically improve your abilities as a developer.

Comment: i just included some code from the CountTopics class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `iterator.remove();`

There's your culprit. You're emptying your map. Don't do this, and it will work. From my limited view on your code, there doesn't seem to be any reason to modify your map. But in case it would be necessary, you should make a copy of the map at the beginning of your method, and work on this copy. Generally it's a bad idea to modify your input parameters, unless that is the specific purpose of that method.

Comment: Thanks, it worked, and yes, I don't need to modify the map, I just need the values from the map